# Angular in 60ish minutes routes issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

I was wondering if someone could take a quick gander at my code and let me know if I am missing anything.  I am trying to learn Angular.js, and have been using the famous [Angular.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM) in 60ish minutes video. However the problem that I have is that angular has been updated since, and things are a little bit different. As a result I am having trouble orchestrating my routes properly.  Much thanks to anyone in advance.

What I am really wondering is, could any body tell me what it is that I am missing in order to make these routes properly work?

This below is my scripts in my html. I followed the book, and as a result they are script tags within my index.html page.

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['helperModule']);
    var controllers = {};

    demoApp.controller("CustomersController",  function ($scope){
        $scope.customers = [
                {name: 'Dave Jones', city: 'pheonix'},
                {name: 'Dave Jones', city: 'New york'},
                {name: 'Jones suman', city: 'pheonix'},
                {name: 'Naresh babu', city: 'Hyderabad'}
            ];
        });
    var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);
        demoApp.config(function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider
                .when('/',
                    {
                        controller: "SimpleController",
                        templateUrl: "views/view1.html"
                    })
                .when('partial2',
                    {
                        controller: "SimpleController"
                        templateUrl: "views/view2.html"
                    })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/"})
        });

        $scope.addCustomer = function(){
            $scope.customers.push({name: $scope.newCustomer.name, city: $scope.newCustomer.city});
        }
<script src = "angular-route.js"></script>
```

This is what I have for my view #1 and view#2 respectively. I feel like everything is correct, however I cannot get any of the names of the customers to appear.

```
<div cass = "container">
<h2>View 1</h2>
    Name: 
    <input type = "text" data-ng-model="filter.name" />
    <ul><li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name"></ul>
    Customer Name: <br />
    <input type= "text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name" />
    Customer City: <br />
    <input type= "text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.city" />
    <button data-ng-click="addCustomer()"> Add Customer </button>   
    <a href="#/view2"> View 2</a>   
</div>



<div cass = "container">
<h2>View </h2>
<div ng-controller="CustomersController">
    Search: <input type = "text" ng-model="searchText" />
    {{ searchText }}
    <br />
    <h3> Customers </h3>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:city">
                <td>{{ cust.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ cust.city }}</td>
                <td>{{ cust.total | currency}} </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors when you check the console?

Comment: I'm guessing the missing `,` after `controller: "SimpleController"` is a copy-paste problem. Also `$scope.addCustomer` is not inside something that has a `$scope`. Could you show us a running fiddle?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I included your pointings to my answer..Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overriding your app that is making problem

start with `var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['helperModule']);` then 
again you did declare `demoApp`
`var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['helperModule']);`

Better way to solve this issue would be do declare you app only once with all dependency & go on amending it with components like controller, directive, factory, etc.

**Code**

```
//could remove `helperModule` module if not used
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['helperModule', 'ngRoute']); 
demoApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: "SimpleController",
            templateUrl: "views/view1.html"
        })
        .when('partial2', {
            controller: "SimpleController",
            templateUrl: "views/view2.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        })
});

demoApp.controller("CustomersController", function($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [{
        name: 'Dave Jones',
        city: 'pheonix'
    }, {
        name: 'Dave Jones',
        city: 'New york'
    }, {
        name: 'Jones suman',
        city: 'pheonix'
    }, {
        name: 'Naresh babu',
        city: 'Hyderabad'
    }];

    $scope.addCustomer = function() {
        $scope.customers.push({
            name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
            city: $scope.newCustomer.city
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Correct, by definition of the second parameter to the module function... `If specified then new module is being created. If unspecified then the module is being retrieved for further configuration.` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module under usage)

Comment: I agree here, you shouldn't be using `var demoApp =` twice.  Also, it seems you named your controller `CustomersController` but are calling for `SimpleController` in your routes.